# SQL CURSOR to pack list items into a variable... but need more

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my stored procedure I'm populating a variable [MyVariable] with it's own set of list items by calling a custom function which uses CURSOR/FETCH.

```
SQL: SELECT dbo.udf_GrabStuff(@ID) AS MyListItems

<ul id="comments">
    *** All of the li elements are from the fetch ***
    <li>
        <div>This is an item</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>This is another item</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What would be the most optimal method of returning more than one list, but all packed within the same [MyVariable] so I can return this.

```
<ul id="comments">
    *** All of the li elements are from the fetch ***
    <li>
        <div>This is an item</div>
        *** This item had children
        <ul id="something">
            <li>Child item</li>
            <li>Child item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>This is another item</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you for your help!

////////// Continued Explanation

I have a stored procedure which queries a list of products from Product table. Comments for those products are stored in Comment table. In my stored procedure I select all the info about products, and then I need to pass full html code for ul, li, and so on into a [Comment] variable. I've successfully done this with cursor/fetch but the more I read I hear it's a bad idea.

What I'd like to do to take this to the next level is have child comments inside of the parent comments, so my initial thought was calling another cursor function from within the first to load as needed per parent comment, but it sounds like there's a much better way.

So lets say my end result is:

```
<ul id="parentcomments">
  <li id="parent1">
    <div>This is a parent comment</div>
    <ul id="childrenforparent1">
      <li id="child1">
        <div>This is a child comment</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="parent2">
  ... and so on
</ul>
```

But again, I need this all in one [Comments] variable passed back to my main SPROC. I can do the child comments easily by AJAX but would rather render them at run-time from server.

Comment: ***WHY*** on earth use a cursor here? You should put your effort into **eliminating** that cursor! I'm almost 100% sure this can be done **without** a crappy, performance-killing cursor......

Comment: While waiting for responses I've stumbled upon multiple articles reinforcing your comment. I'd be glad to use a better method. I'm just not sure of what direction to go. In the SPROC I'm returning list of data. In that list of data, one of those variables is for comments. I need those comments to also include children comments IF they exist. And I need all of this to be packed into one final variable so generating the HTML within the function is necessary and some comments do not have replies, whereas others do.

Comment: @marc_s I extended my explanation... Not sure if it helps. Hope so. I want to use whatever method is best for this purpose. Thank you for your response.

Comment: It is difficult to offer an answer here without more insight into your data model. Maybe you could set up the bare bones of your data model in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)? Create the tables and populate with a couple rows of data?

Comment: First time using SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/103f4/7

So in the last part of my example above is how I need to return data to the variable. I need to generate HTML into one variable, and for it to be smart enough to append the additional inline UL for comment replies if they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my solution after a painful learning process and no sleep! The response time is super fast as well.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetParentComments]
(
  @ProductID INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @Comments VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Comments = STUFF((SELECT ' ' + 
    '<li id="Comment_' + CAST(CommentID AS VARCHAR) + '"' + '>' + 
        CAST(Comment_Comment AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + 
        '<ul>' + CAST(dbo.udf_GetCommentReplies(CommentID) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '</ul>' + 
    '</li>' 

    FROM Product_Comment


    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @Comments = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Comments, '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>'); 



RETURN @Comments

END



GO
```

The second function called within the first is identical to this one, yet returns the replies instead. I had to use REPLACE to sustain the HTML format as XML safe strips it out otherwise.

Anyone have a better solution than this? So far this enables me to pack a hierarchical list of parents and children within a single SQL variable.